# How to efficiently cluster small squares into larger square grids

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to construct a square grid made of squares such that depending on how many small squares I have, I construct the appropriate grid.

This would work in cases of perfect squares -- 3x3, or 4x4 or 5x5 grids -- or when not enough squares are present, so the top row needs to be incomplete.

So for example if I have 10 small squares (6 fewer than needed for a 4x4 grid), I'll construct a 3x4 grid (3 row, 4 column), and add one square to the top of the grid to make a 4th row.

It seems like I'll do this by taking the square root of the number of squares I have, then roundup. We'll call numsquaresperrow that value.

In D3. I'll then need to append my rectangles like this:

```
//var numsquaresperrow determined already. 

chartmarks.selectAll(".squares")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr('class','squares')
      .attr('width','8px')
      .attr('height',8px')
      .attr('x',(numsquaresperrow * (width + offset)) / 2)
      .attr('y',function(d,i) {
          // use a modulo to break to the new line once the iter passes numsquaresperrow
       });
```

Is there a more effective way to do this and to try the grid?

Comment: your example is not clear you have 10 squares you make 3 row*4column grid but 3*4 is 12 so why are you making a 4th row? can you put a screen shot of what you want

Comment: I guess I'm saying there aren't always enough smaller squares to make the larger square. But I want to get as close as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood your problem.

Here is my try.

I made an array of rows and column.
If the row has 1 display the rectangle and in 0 display is none.

```js
var number = 10; //change this as per your choice.
//make the data
var cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number))
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  var d = new Array(cols).fill(0);//make an array of 0
  data.push(d)
}

for (var i = cols -1; i >= 0; i--) {
 for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
  if(number > 0){
   data[i][k] = 1;//if number > 0 make it as 1
  }
  number--;
 }
}


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//make svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   //make rectangle grid
var column = 0;
svg
  .selectAll("cols")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 10
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
  if (i ==0)
   column++;
    return column * 10;
  })
 .style("fill", function(d){
   return "red"
 })
 .style("display", function(d){
    if (d == 0)
    return "none"
   else 
    return "block"
 })
 .style("stroke", function(d){
   return "white"
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```